# Multiple entities in one form [Symfony 3]

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, formbuilder

Here are my tables:

**Movie**

- id
- name
- year
- description

**Person**

- id
- name
- date_of_birth

**Role**

- id
- name
- movie_id
- person_id

So, Movie should contain, obviously, movies. Person consists of people (actors, directors or writers). Table Role connects with other 2 tables by having `$movie` and `$person` variable inside its class, with Many-to-One relationship for both of them, which in the end results in *movie_id* & *person_id*.

What I want to achieve is having a *form*, where I will be able to insert new movie, but also its relevant actors, director(s) & writer(s).

Final form result should contain these fields:

- movie_name, movie_year, movie_description
- dropdown with list of persons from DB (person.name)
- dropdown with 3 possibilities - actor, director, writer (which would eventually be inserted to DB)

So, after filling out the first three inputs, user chooses a person from a dropdown list, and then, chooses appropriate role for chosen person. If I'm thinking right, I should be able to SELECT from Person (name) table , and to INSERT into Movie (name, year, descr.) & Role (name, movie_id, person_id) tables.

I'm aware that I should be using [Form collections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html), but I don't understand how to use them, at least in this situation. I guess I should start by creating something like RoleModel class, but not sure whether I made a mistake before going into this, which makes this problem more complex than it should be. 
My questions really is - **how to make this work with Form collections**?

I can provide any necessary code, if needed.

Comment: You are looking for nested forms in Symfony, take a loot at their example : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: yes, I have already seen that. I mentioned that link in my question... but I would need some sort of guidance to solve this, even if it's through nesting, as you said

Answer (score 0):

Symfony make it really easy, so first, you need to add bidirectional relation (One-to-many) between your person entity and your movie entity so you need to:

- Add property called person to your movie entity:

Code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Person", inversedBy="movies")
 */
protected $person;
```

- Add property called movies to your person entity:

Code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Movie", mappedBy="person")
 */
protected $movies;
```

Now in your MovieType file (form configuration file) you can do it by:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('year')
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('person', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'        => Person::class, //This existed usually in (AppBundle\Entity\Person)
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ));
}
```

This is a simple demonstration on how to use EntityType in Symfony.

Good luck.

Comment: Creating `$person` within Movie class, consequently creates _person_id_ inside that class, and personally, I don't think I need that. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also, did you accidentally wrote movie**s** in plural or?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by embedding FormTypes, you can create a new one which is a composition of a `PersonFormType` and `MovieFormType`, and it would need an extra field for the role type (director, actor, etc)
Then, after submit, you can retrieve your objects something like this:

```
// SomeController's action
...
$data = $form->getData();
$person = $data['person'] // or whatever is the name of the field
```

You can find more information about embedding FormTypes in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/cur...